# exec: 2508: /tmp/install.dir.30906/Linux/resource/jre/bin/java: not found

Tags: software-installation, java

After running:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ferramroberto/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre sun-java6-plugin sun-java6-fonts
```

I try to setup a software sybase `sudo ./setup.bin` but I get the following problem:

```
exec: 2508: /tmp/install.dir.30906/Linux/resource/jre/bin/java: not found
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error occurs because the installer is itself a 32-bit binary using 32-bit binaries, which may cause problems on a 64-bit machine. It needs 32-bit libraries installed.

On an Ubuntu 64-bit Linux machine, to work around this issue, install the package "ia32-libs":

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Answer (score 3):

For folks coming to this answer in 2016 and Ubuntu 14.04+, the solution is now:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-i386
```

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 16.04 does not have the `ia32-libs` package. You need to install `lib32ncurses5`:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32ncurses5
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding 32 bit support to my 64 bit computer fixed this for me. On Windows in WSL2 with Debian Linux I was able to add 32 bit support with the following:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install libncurses5:i386
```