# Installing Novell Designer

Tags: installation, java, jre

i try to install Novell Designer 4.0.1 on Ubuntu.

But i get the error message:

```
Preparing to install...
Extracting the JRE from the installer archive...
Unpacking the JRE...
Extracting the installation resources from the installer archive...
Configuring the installer for this system's environment...

Launching installer...

./install: 2468: exec: /tmp/install.dir.4347/Linux/resource/jre/bin/java: not found
```

What could i do to get the installation working?

Comment: I found a solution here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/189360/exec-2508-tmp-install-dir-30906-linux-resource-jre-bin-java-not-found